# Enabling Lightning LockerService Security says - Helper data undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning, locker-service

I've two functions in a component helper, which calls another function like below:

```
 ({
    data1: null,
    data2: null,
    data: null,

    get1 : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.UserDetails");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          var state = response.getState();
          if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            this.data1 = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('get1:', this.data1 , this.data2);
            this.process(component);
          }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    get2 : function(component) {
        this.data2 = 35;
        console.log('get2:', this.data1 , this.data2);
        this.process(component);
    },
    process : function(component) {
        console.log('process:', this.data1 , this.data2);
        if(this.data1 && this.data2) {
            this.data = {name: this.data1.FirstName, age: this.data2};
            component.set('v.user', this.data);
        }
    }
})
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.get1(component);
        helper.get2(component);
    }
})
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="LightningLearnerController" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="user" type="object" />
    <div>Name: {!v.user.name}</div>
    <div>Age: {!v.user.age}</div>
</aura:component>
```

This was working fine until I enabled Lightning LockerService Security. When I set either data1 or data2 the other is being set to undefined, hence the process function is never executed as the if loop condition is always false.

Any pointers/suggestions on how to fix are most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is the use of `this` keyword inside of the action's callback function.

Every JS function has a `this`,and the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called and it behaves differently in strict mode which is enforced by the LockerService(for more info on `this` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) ).

This is what happening inside the `get1`:

```
get1 : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.UserDetails");
        var self = this;
        // THIS points to the Helper's context where the `data1,data2,data,other helper functions` resides
        console.log(this) // THIS is different from below THIS inside of the action 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            /* 
            THIS point to the action's(i.e ActionService) context, 
            because its the one that invoked the callback function
            */
            console.log(this); 
            console.log(this === self); // return false
        });
}
```

So, all you have to do is store the helper's context in variable, and use it to call other helper methods inside the actions's callback like this:

```
get1 : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.UserDetails");
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          var state = response.getState();
          if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            self.data1 = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('get1:', self.data1 , self.data2);
            self.process(component);
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. Overlook :(
I wonder why it is working when LockerService is disabled.

Comment: @SuryaChandraRaoGandreddi As Praveen pointed out that Locker Service makes enforces your Javascript to use "strict" mode .Refer the link thats been added in the answer

Comment: @praveen Great answer !